# Can I take the front rotors and put them in the back

Tags: brakes, brake-rotor

I have some front rotors from when I replaced them it looks like I didn't need them so I kept them. I would like to take them to get shaved and put the in the back. Is this possible to do something like that?

Comment: There is not enough information for anyone to be able to answer this question, the only possible answer at this point is "maybe."

Comment: We need to know the make, model and year

Answer (score 2):

I would give it about a 99.9% probability that they will not exchange front to back. I've never ran into a set where you could (not ruling out there might be *some vehicle out there which you can*). The main reason for this is they are designed differently. The front brakes do about 70-75% (depends on the manufacture) of the braking for the vehicle. Because of this, they are built with more machined surface already built into it than the back has. They are often quite a bit wider diameter (which gives the rotor a mechanical advantage) and thicker (provides for better heat dispersion) than the back for the same purpose. And as @barbecue has stated, the rear brakes often have the accommodation for emergency (parking) brakes, which I've never come across before for front braking systems.

Something you can do with them, though, is if there is enough meat on them (thick enough) to accept machining, get them machined and save them for the *next time* you need to replace your front brake rotors. To keep them preserved, do the following:

- Get them machined.
- Clean them thoroughly.
- Get large thick mil plastic Ziploc style bags (or vacuum storage bags) to store them in.
- Coat the rotors liberally with a good coat of WD-40 (specifically use this brand).
- Put them in the bag(s) along with some [oxygen absorption packets](http://www.nitro-pak.com/oxygen-absorbers-pak-of-50). You may want to place these in a folded up paper towel or something so the WD-40 doesn't absorb into them and keep them from absorbing the oxygen.
- Squeeze out as much air as you can and seal the Ziploc fastener.

Something along this lines should keep them from rusting for a long period of time. You may want to keep an eye on them every once in a while to ensure they are in good shape. Do so without opening the bag.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, I'd just take a wild guess and say probably not. Often front and rear rotors are different. Sometimes the front rotors are larger, and in many cases, rear rotors are slightly different to accommodate the parking brake. One quick option would be to find part numbers for front and rear rotors for your vehicle and see if they're the same part.
More information on your vehicle might get you a better answer.